# Is there a way to make Adjustment Layers ignore certain layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers

Is it possible to insert a Hue/Saturation adjustment layer at the top of all layers - but make it so that chosen layers are not affected by it?

Can it be done without altering positions? (Ie. moving this layer down, and moving up the ones that I want to keep unchanged.)

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to change layer order? or why you don't just turn layers on and off as needed?

Comment: Hi Lauren, yes. I think this would make color schemes changes very easy and fast. For example, when you're designing a website and the client wants to see a different color scheme, you can just change the hue on the adjustment layer, and all the other stuff changes automatically. and you can create like 20 color variations of the design pretty easy :D

Answer (score 3):

Make groups on which layer set you want to apply hue and saturation,this will affect only group items.I attached a SS to make it clear please let me know if you have any confusion.

[image]

according to your above comment i would suggest you to check the concept of layer comps it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using a clipping mask.  Check out the help docs for the exact steps to create a clipping mask.